# Delete all ActiveX Checkboxes and then create new ones starting from 1

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a button that creates checkboxes. If I press it again I want to delete the previous checkboxes made and replace them with new ones. This is the code for the delete and create new part:

```
Dim s As Shape
For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If s.Type = 12 Then
        If Not Intersect(s.TopLeftCell, Sheets("EmpChoice").Range("A14:T33")) Is Nothing Then
            s.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
Dim obj As Object
Dim rng As Range


For i = 1 To EmployeeNo
If i > 6 And i < 13 Then   'Just code that spaces the checkboxes out evenly
    col = 3
    offset = 12
ElseIf i >= 13 Then
    col = 5
    offset = 24
Else
    col = 1
    offset = 0
End If
Set rng = Sheets("EmpChoice").Cells(14 + (i * 2) - offset, col)
    cellLeft = rng.Left
    cellTop = rng.Top
    cellwidth = rng.Width
    cellheight = rng.Height


Set obj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Checkbox.1", Left:=cellLeft, Top:=cellTop, Width:=cellwidth * 2, Height:=cellheight * 2)
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Caption = EmployeeList(i)
Next i
```

The problem is that if the code creates 18 checkboxes and then deletes them, the new ones starts with the name "CheckBox19", crashing the code. Is it possible to make sure that the new checkboxes starts at "CheckBox1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying inserting of the obj name, like in the next piece of code:

```
Set obj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Checkbox.1", Left:=cellLeft, Top:=cellTop, Width:=cellwidth * 2, Height:=cellheight * 2)
obj.Name = "CheckBox" & i 'Here you can choose the name you need...
                          'Otherwise, VBA keeps track of the previous created objects
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Caption = EmployeeList(i)
```

Comment: @Jens: Glad helping you! But, when an answer solves your problem it is good to tick the code left side check box, making it the accepted answer. In such a way, if somebody else will look for something similar, he would know that the answer worked...